# Создать соединение веб-приложения Java на Tomcat с MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

Есть простое приложение на Java для тестов на присоединение к базе данных MySQL. Что я делал:

В `web.xml` добавил вот это:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">


<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>
    jdbc/library
</res-ref-name>
<res-type>
    javax.sql.DataSource
</res-type>
<res-auth>
    Container
</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Создал файл `context.xml` в `META-INF` ,там прописал вот это

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context >

<Resource name="jdbc/library"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="admin"
          password="admin"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library"
          maxTotal="8"
          maxIdle="4"/>

        </Context>
```

Далее создал простой Java класс для теста конекта:

```
   package test;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class tt1  {
    public void check() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)
            envCtx.lookup("jdbc/library");

    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    if (conn==null) {
        System.out.println("failed");
    } else System.out.println("connection is good");
        conn.close();

    }

}
```

Далее в `Index.jsp` прописал вот это:

```
     <%@ page import="test.tt1" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <h2>
    <%
      tt1 ss=new tt1();
      ss.check();

    %>
  </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Далее у меня есть два файла первый `mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar`, который я вытащил из коннектора, который установился вместе с сервером
и второй файл `mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar`, который я вытащил из архива к прошлым версиям томкат. Этот файл я кладу в папку `TOMCAT/lib`

Если кладу первый файл, то получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
rg.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/index.jsp] at line [18]

15:   <h2>
16:     <%
17:       tt1 ss=new tt1();
18:       ss.check();
19: 
20:     %>
21:   </h2>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:607)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:148)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:458)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2224)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2104)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
    test.tt1.check(tt1.java:17)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:458)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2209)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2104)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
    test.tt1.check(tt1.java:17)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:458)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Если кладу файл нормер два получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Stacktrace:

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:607)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:148)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:458)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2224)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2104)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
    test.tt1.check(tt1.java:17)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:458)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver.parseFabricURL(FabricMySQLDriver.java:97)
    com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver.acceptsURL(FabricMySQLDriver.java:93)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:299)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2209)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2104)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
    test.tt1.check(tt1.java:17)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:458)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Перепробовал уже все что только можно. Пересмотрел всю документацию. Не пойму почему не работает?

Answer (score 0):

- Скачайте 6 или 8 версию [коннектора](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)
- Используйте `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` вместо `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
- Зарегистрируйте драйвер и попробуйте напрямую вбить значения для соединения:

  ```
  public class tt1  {
  public void check() {
  Connection connection = null;
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library", "admin", "admin");
          if(connection.isValid) System.out.println("connection is good");
          else System.out.println("failed");
      } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  ```

P.S. Maven избавляет от необходимости вручную возиться с jar-никами

Comment: для web application такой метод не подходит

Comment: Ну и даже если напряму вбивать -не работает ваш метод .те же самые ошибки кидает.Проблема тут мне видится в том ,что загрузчик не может загрузить драйвер -почему вопрос и что с этим делать непонятно.

Comment: вообщем решение нашлось путем тыка.сначала добавляем коннектор вручную в библиотеку проекта,причем работает только 5я версия,8я не работает.далее нужно прописать вот такой код    ` Driver driver;
       Connection con;
        driver=new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","admin","admin");`